# Delphi: DBGrid Column Title Hint - force to reset the hint?

Tags: delphi, controls, title, dbgrid, hint

I thought that I implement column title hint into my own DBGrid.
It's seems to be simple - I thought.

I added

TitleHints : TStrings

that contains information in this format:

name=value

Where name is (0-99) for non-field-based columns, and fieldname for field based columns.
Value is the Hint of the column, crlf is \n.

Everything is ok, OnMouseMove is the the Hint based on position.

But: only the first hint shown, the nexts are not.
I think this is because the hint mechanism is activated at mouse arriving into the "Control"... When I leave the Control, and come again, I get another hint - once.
No matter I set ShowHint to off.

Because I don't want to create my own HintWIndow if possible, I search for a way to reset the Hint mechanism to the Applicaion believe: this is the first case in this control.
Can I do it any way, like "send message", or call "cancelhint" if this exists, etc.

Do you know about this way?

Thanks for your help, and good day to you!

Regards:
    dd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reactivate the hint in your overridden `MouseMove`, e.g.:

```
type
  TDBGrid = class(DBGrids.TDBGrid)
  private
    FLastHintColumn: Integer;
  protected
    procedure CMHintShow(var Message: TCMHintShow); message CM_HINTSHOW;
    function GetColumnTitleHint(Col: Integer): string;
    procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;


procedure TDBGrid.CMHintShow(var Message: TCMHintShow);
var
  Cell: TGridCoord;
begin
  if not Assigned(Message.HintInfo) or not (dgTitles in Options) then
    inherited
  else
  begin
    Cell := MouseCoord(Message.HintInfo^.CursorPos.X, Message.HintInfo^.CursorPos.Y);
    if Cell.Y = 0 then
    begin
      FLastHintColumn := Cell.X - 1;
      Message.HintInfo^.HintStr := GetColumnTitleHint(FLastHintColumn);
    end
    else
      FLastHintColumn := -1;
  end;
end;

function TDBGrid.GetColumnTitleHint(Col: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := Columns[Col].Title.Caption + ' hint';
end;

procedure TDBGrid.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  Cell: TGridCoord;
begin
  inherited MouseMove(Shift, X, Y);
  if dgTitles in Options then
  begin
    Cell := MouseCoord(X, Y);
    if Cell.Y = 0 then
    begin
      if Cell.X - 1 <> FLastHintColumn then
        Application.ActivateHint(Mouse.CursorPos);
    end
    else
      Application.CancelHint;
  end;
end;

constructor TDBGrid.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FLastHintColumn := -1;
end;
```

`GetColumnTitleHint` is only an example, you should implement it to return the correct value from your `TitleHints` property.

Hope this helps.